# Using mysql command line to generate CSV, can't generate it in any other directory except /tmp

Tags: mysql, csv, permissions

I am creating csv and mysql dumps via mysql command line.
For creating mysql file I can easily created the .sql dump in my required directory

```
 mysqldump  -u"root" -p"root"  dns packet --where="server_id=1 > /var/www/mydatafile/SQLData.sql
```

that works all okay but in case of CSV, it only creates the files in TMP folder, it can't create files in any other location

```
 mysql -u"root" -p""  dns -e "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/mydatafile/my_csv.csv'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM TABLENAME";
```

it says

```
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create/write to file '/var/www/mydatafile/my_csv.csv' (Errcode: 13)
```

I have given permission to the www directory but still it gives the same error...May I know the reason behind not creating the CSV into anyother location while SQL can be generated easily..

Answer (score 0):

your directory `/var/www/mydatafile/` has to be writable by the mysql user (usually `mysql`). You can check which user in file `my.cnf` (in debian/ubuntu based, located in `/etc/mysql/` ).

The first command works because you generate sql instruction to stdout and redirect the output to a file, so that use the current user environment.

The second command is internal to mysql, so correct permissions are required for the mysql user.

**EDIT:** you can alternatively [use `mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html) to generate csv with a command like this:

```
mysqldump -u"root" -p"root"  dns packet -p -t --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n"
```

Comment: so do i need to give mysql:mysql to that directory or what?

Comment: This is all that i can see in my.cnf in /etc directory

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: You can set mysql:mysql to that directory, or add group write permissions + add the matching group to the mysql existing group (`usermod -G -a thegroup mysql`), or allow everyone to write on it (what I not recommend if it's a server). It's up to you to choose what fits your needs  (+ I edited my answer for an alternative solution :) )

Comment: changed the user using chown mysql:mysql .. still gives the same error.. alternate solution didn't work..it says 


mysqldump -u"root" -p"root"  dns packet -p -t --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n"

Comment: I just tested the `chown` solution and that worked. Be sure the file perms has been changed with `ls -lA`. And check `mysql` is the right user for mysql (see the line in my.cnf `user = [your mysql user]`). (See the link to mysql documentation I added previously in my answer)

Comment: chown mysql:mysql mydatafile .... checked the my.cnf it is mysql...so should work right?? what do you mean by ls -lA ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far

Comment: `sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/www/mydatafile/;sudo chmod u+rwx /var/www/mydatafile/`